# Ввод и вывод двумерного массива действительных чисел

Tags: c

```
#define SIZE 1

int main(){

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    float arr[SIZE][SIZE];
    int i,j;

    printf("Введите матрицу %d x %d\n",SIZE+1,SIZE+1);// ввод матрицы

    for(i=0;i<=SIZE;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=SIZE;j++){
            printf("\tArray[%d,%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%f",&arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

system("cls");

    for(i=0;i<=SIZE;i++){//вывод матрицы
        for(j=0;j<=SIZE;j++){
            printf("Array[%d,%d] = %g \t",i,j,arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Нужно ввести с клавиатуры и вывести массив действительных чисел.

Но 1 цикл выполняется почему-то 3 раза вместо 4. И результат вывод неверный.
Подозреваю что проблема в спецификаторах.

Comment: У вас как минимум запарывается память при вводе (`i<=SIZE`, `j<=SIZE`), а дальше может происходить что угодно.

Comment: @PinkTux, можно подробнее узнать почему ? Из-за использования константы ?

Comment: Из-за  того, что размер у вас `SIZE`, а вы записываете `SIZE+1` данных. Посккольку индексация идёт с нуля, то правильное условие - не `<=`, а `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как вы определили препроцессорную константу равную 1

```
#define SIZE 1
```

то данное объявление массива

```
float arr[SIZE][SIZE];
```

эквивалентно следующему объявлению

```
float arr[1][1];
```

То есть ваш массив имеет один элемент с индексами `arr[0][0]`.

Поэтому вам следует записать

```
printf("Введите матрицу %d x %d\n",SIZE,SIZE);// ввод матрицы
                                   ^^^^^^^^^

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        ^^^^^^
    for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++){
            ^^^^^^  
        printf("\tArray[%d,%d]=",i,j);
        scanf("%f",&arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Аналогично записывается и второй цикл.

Имейте в виду, что согласно стандарту языка C функция `main` без параметров должны объявляться как

```
int main( void )
```